# Crystal Reports XI - Error de Sintaxis en consulta con parametros dinámicos

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

Vamos por partes dijo Jack el Destripador:

1. Tengo que editar un reporte gigante y Horrible a través de Crystal Reports.
2. Por razones de compatibilidad del software del que proviene el reporte, he tenido que llegar a insertar un subreporte dentro del reporte para acceder a determinado dato.

Entonces:

1. Conecto a mi Base con una conexion SQL Server 2.
2. Voy a agregar comando.
3. Copio la consulta que funciona fenomenal en el Managment Studio 2008 y me dispongo a agregar los parámetros necesarios, quedando la consulta de la siguiente manera:

.

```
SELECT TOP 1 isnull( dtssegcabv.dscv_fecharecepcion,0) as FechaRecepcion
FROM CabVenta
JOIN dtssegcabv ON CabVenta.cvescv_id = dtssegcabv.scv_id
WHERE CabVenta.cve_letra = {?cve_letra} 
      AND CabVenta.cve_codpvt={?cve_codpvt} 
      AND CabVenta.cve_nro={?cve_nro} 
      AND CabVenta.cvetco_cod={?cvetco_cod}
```

Se abre un diálogo de Introducir valores (entiendo que son valores de prueba , o valores por defecto ? no entiendo bien). El tema es que:

> -Si agrego un valor a cada parámetro (un valor válido en la BDD):
>
> Entonces interpreta todos esos valores como un nombre de columna. Por
>   ejemplo, si al parametro cve_letra le Asigno A , me dice 'Invalid
>   Column name A'

---

> -Si dejo los parámetros vacíos:
>
> 'Incorrect Syntax near the keyword and'
>
> Insisto en que la consulta ejecutada en SQL Managment Studio 2008
>   funciona.

Gracias por su ayuda, voy a estar atento a comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

1. Cada vez que programes en SQL, todos los nombres reservados colocalos en mayúsculas, así te será más sencillo determinar cuáles son los valores.
2. Los `SELECT` van en una línea, los `FROM` van en la línea siguiente, así sucesivamente para tener mayor claridad de lo que se hace.
3. Cuando hay varias condiciones, debajo del `WHERE` agrega sangría.

Entre más fácil de leer sea la query, más felicidad para quien la desarrolla y quien le dará mantenimiento.

Ahora con el código, revisa lo siguiente:

```
SELECT TOP 1 isnull( dtssegcabv.dscv_fecharecepcion,0) AS FechaRecepcion
FROM CabVenta
JOIN dtssegcabv ON CabVenta.cvescv_id = dtssegcabv.scv_id
WHERE CabVenta.cve_letra = '{?cve_letra}' --Notese las comillas simples alrededor
      AND CabVenta.cve_codpvt= {?cve_codpvt} 
      AND CabVenta.cve_nro = {?cve_nro} 
      AND CabVenta.cvetco_cod={?cvetco_cod}
```

Espero que con esto pueda dar solución a tu pregunta :D y si no, al menos colaboramos para que haya mejor redacción de queries :D

Comment: malditas comillas ....

Comment: "teik it isi bro", a todos nos pasa, ten mucho cuidado con los UPDATE y/o DELETE sin el WHERE. Que sigas compilando con éxito y con todo el power 2.0!!! Saludos :D